# Remoting configuration failed with the exception: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, remoting

I have added Dot net remoting support in my code (following code and App.config which conatains remoting configuration)

.
.
.

```
  RemotingConfiguration.Configure("App.Config", false);
```

.
.
.
App.config

```
    <!-- This channel uses GTCP from Genuine Channel, client application must use this channel access. /!-->
    <channel type="Belikov.GenuineChannels.GenuineTcp.GenuineTcpChannel, GenuineChannels" MaxTimeSpanToReconnect="240000" ReconnectionTries="0" port="8080">
```

.
.
.

.
.

I am seeing exception

> Remoting configuration failed with the exception
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>
> at
>   Belikov.GenuineChannels.GenuineTcp.TcpConnectionManager.StartListening(Object
>   endPointAsObject)
>
> at
>   Belikov.GenuineChannels.GenuineTcp.GenuineTcpChannel.StartListening(Object
>   data)
>
> at
>   Belikov.GenuineChannels.GenuineTcp.GenuineTcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary
>   properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider iClientChannelSinkProvider,
>   IServerChannelSinkProvider iServerChannelSinkProvider)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args,
>   SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(Object[] args,
>   SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringType)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)
>
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.CreateChannelFromConfigEntry(ChannelEntry
>   entry)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.ConfigureChannels(RemotingXmlConfigFileData
>   configData, Boolean ensureSecurity)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.ConfigureRemoting(RemotingXmlConfigFileData
>   configData, Boolean ensureSecurity)'.

I am bit confused as it was using fine earlier, same code giving me an error.

can anybody help me to figure out whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I changed port ID from 8080 to 62388

it solved my issue. But still not able to figure out why it is giving me an error for 8080

Comment: It's usually a firewall blocking 8080 as it's a common port used for http traffic.